# Strategies to avoid code duplication in web application

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, visual-studio, code-duplication

I'm trying to find the best solution for a big problem with code duplication. We have an `ASP.NET Web Api` backend with an `Angular` frontend. Our backend solution also has multiples projects holding the `Business Logic` and `DAO` for access to the database.

Now, the problem is we have multiple customers, each one has a different UI with sometimes different `Javascript` code, but the backend remains the same. So, currently, for each customer we create a new project in `Visual Studio` with almost all the client side code being duplicated + the UI changes and also all the `Controllers` from the backend being duplicated too, as well as files as `Global.asax`, OWIN auth, etc.

This is becoming nightmare, there is a LOT of code duplicated and it's a pain to maintain. I have think some options:

- Have a different `.js`, `.css`, `.html` file for each customer, but only for the files we change, then, when deploying, tell `Visual Studio` which file to deploy according to the configuration (I don't know if this is possible)
- Find some tool that allows us to conditionally change code in javascript in the same way `Visual Studio` does with `Web.config` for the different deploy configurations
- Look for another approach/architecture for the code?

Comment: would this be better suited for programmers.se?

Comment: If a moderator thinks so, feel free to move up :)

Comment: I'm not giving this as an answer because it's actually hard to do, and may be dependent on your VC system. I actually split the project where the back end code is in one directory, and the front end code for each project is in another directory, with the common angularJS code in a git subtree. To start a new client project, we "[fork](http://www.woodcp.com/2014/01/how-to-fork-git-repositories-on-visual-studio-online/)" our base project's front end and branch the back end (so we can set connection strings and such). Client-specific changes go outside the subtree in the client project.

Comment: To the downvoter, would you mind explaining why the downvote?

Comment: Often people downvote if they're not capable of understanding the question. It sucks, but I've seen it more than once.

Comment: Are they skins of the same or quite different.

Comment: The skins are almost the same, only small details changes, some behaviour , colors, styles, text

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a project in multiple solutions.

I would build a series of common projects and then individual customer projects which pull in and "finish" the web app.

It would probably be prudent to make that final customer project a template to make sure nothing gets missed.

Comment: It's not that straightforward, since .Net basically forces a structure where your services are all jumbled up with your client side code and all the pfm means you don't have much chance of understanding how all the dependencies on the various projects interrelate until things break really hard.

Comment: This answer basically says, "build a product line" in an ad hoc way.  See my answer for a more organized approach.   OP's objection about dependencies is essentially right; they have to captured in an organized way so the generated systems DO NOT break.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is convert your multiple systems into a [product line](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/productlines/).

A product line is a software code base plus configuration management driven by (product) features [in OP's case, a feature might be a customer-name].   The features specify the specific properties of a particular product line instance.  The configuration management tools use the feature specification to pick out the parts of the software base that are relevant, and add it to the baseline (completely shared) part of the product.   Good feature managementment will allow some features to imply or deny others to help minimize the problem of getting the right feature set for a product line instance.

Product lines are not easy to build; but then managing a big pile of systems in an ad hoc way that are pretty similar is even harder.

You can use open source tools such as [XVCL](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2868016_XVCL_XML-based_Variant_Configuration_Language) [a kind of "conditional compilation" that works across any kind of source code] or commercial packages such as [BigLever](http://www.biglever.com/) to implement product lines.

To get from your current state into a managed product line will require you to discover what what current systems share, how they vary, and invent a vocabulary to describe the variations as features.  You can do that by hand (painfully). You will likely do better using a [(JavaScript-capable) Clone Detector](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/), and focus on [language-specific commonality extraction.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/Baxter-Churchett-CloneDR-Paper.pdf)  If your software has multiple kinds of artifacts (HTML, JavaScript, SQL, build scripts,...), you may find that an [organized process for discovery of commonality across and within multiple levels (see heading "Refactoring to Product Lines")](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2012/3477/pdf/dagrep_v002_i002_p021_s12071.pdf) is constructive.